# Read html tags as a tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to read HTML elements using jQuery and store it's contents in object like a tree.
for example if I have this:

```
<div class="box">
    <input type="text" data-type="name">
    <div class="box">
        <input type="email" data-type="email">
        <input type="text" data-type="another_input">
        <div class="box">
            <!-- ETC -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then the javascript object would be like:

```
{
    box: {
        name: "input value",
        box: {
            email: "input value",
            another_input: "input_value",
            box: {
                // ETC...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my current cdoe:

```
var items = [];
$( ".root > .box" ).each( function (){
    $(this).find( "*" ).each( function() {
        if( haveChilds( $(this) ) ) {
            // recursing
        } else {
            items[ $(this).data("type") ] = $(this).val();
        }
    });
});

function haveChilds( $element ) {
    if( $element.hasClass( "box" ) )
        return true;
}
```

is there's any easy way to do this in jQuery or Javascript?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can certainly do this in JS or jQuery, but it will not be simple. You'll be best recursing through the DOM. I don't know how you plan on getting the property names consistently though; it seems to change between `class` and `data-type` - what it the element has neither of those? If you want more specific help then please post your current JS code.

Comment: Why don't you just use lists?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Well, this is my current idea, but I was wondering if there's an easiest way to do this.

Comment: what's going to be the purpose of this data exactly? The DOM object model already implements a tree structure which works...

Comment: For us to tell you the easiest way we need to know what your goal is...

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: What if you have two `div`s of class "box" under the same parent element or two inputs of type "text"? An object cannot have twice the same property...

Comment: Grabbing an element in jQuery already builds a tree of sorts. Everything is listed in nested `children` properties.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I edited my answer with my current JS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recurse over the dom tree and children nodes to build an object like this. I am not sure if this is a good idea. You may want to expand on what you actually want, as an end goal, so we can give a proper answer.

```js
function buildDomMap(target) {
  var node = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < target.children.length; i += 1) {
    var child = target.children[i];
    var childName = child.getAttribute("data-type") || child.className;
    if (child instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
      node[childName] = child.value;
    } else /* if (/\bbox\b/.test(child.className)) /* only crawl box? */ {
      node[childName] = buildDomMap(child)
    }
  }
  return node;
}

function buildAndLog() {
  var startingNode = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];
  console.log(JSON.stringify(buildDomMap(startingNode), null, 2))
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <input type="text" data-type="name">
    <div class="box">
        <input type="email" data-type="email">
        <input type="text" data-type="another_input">
        <div class="box">
            <!-- ETC -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button onclick="buildAndLog()">Get data</button>
```